# shortcut for git merging master into current branch

Tags: git

So sometimes I'm working on a branch and I want to pull in the changes made on origin/master since branch created. Just doing `git merge master` is not usually adequate because local master may not have the changes from remote master, so I find myself having to do this:

```
# save any uncommitted changes (if there are any)
git stash  
# update master first:
git checkout master
git pull
# back to where we were:
git checkout <previous branch>
git stash pop # omit if git stash not done
# and finally the actual merge: 
git merge master
```

Surely there is a shorter way, just one or two git commands?

Comment: Why not use git alias to make your own shortcut??? See https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias/blob/master/gitalias.txt for example

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One command:

```
git pull origin master:master
```

Let's me split it and explain. `git pull master:master` is equivalent to

```
git fetch origin master:master
git merge master
```

`git fetch origin master:master` means: fetch new commits from remote `origin` branch `master` and update local branch `master` to point to the same commit as remote `master`. It's what you do with

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout <previous branch>
```

but much faster (no need to do 2 checkouts).

If you need to stash add `--autostash`:

```
git pull --autostash origin master:master
```

Comment: Sweet, I like this! Much nicer than my alias, posted as an alternative answer. I'll leave my alias answer up anyway, in case someone is interested in it.

Comment: Very nice, even the stashing fits in the one command, way to go!

Comment: Just wondering, I know this is quite old but can you add a different merge strategy to this command to? Like making it do a rebase?

Comment: @Tosa The question is about merging.

Comment: @phd , yeah it was more a question and not a critique of your answer :)

Comment: @Tosa Tried `git pull --rebase master:master` ? Or even [`git config --global branch.autoSetupRebase always`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchautoSetupRebase), then `git config --local branch.master.rebase true`, then `git pull origin master:master`.

Comment: This doesn't update the remote tracking branch (origin/master) though - is this a problem?

Comment: @cirex It updates `origin/master`. The command starts with `git fetch origin master:master` which updates both non-currently checked out `master` and remote tracking branch `origin/master`.

Answer (score 1):

I face your scenario constantly and rapidly got tired of doing it more or less like you described, so I created an alias to fast-forward `master` without switching to it.

I have created an alias in the `[alias]` section of my `~/.gitconfig` to update `master` (or any branch) to `origin/master` without checking it out.

Here is a simple (but unsafe) version of this alias:

```
    ff = !sh -c 'git update-ref refs/heads/$1 origin/$1' -
```

You call it by typing `git ff some_branch`, and it uses `update-ref` to set that branch to `origin/some_branch`.

Once this alias is defined, your operation becomes:

```
git fetch
git ff master
git merge master
```

However, this is unsafe because it will do the update even if is not equivalent to a fast-forward merge, and therefore it might discard some commits. Here is the second version of this alias, with a safeguard so that it only does fast-forwarding, and refuses to do anything in other situations:

```
    # Do a fast-forward merge on the branch specified as argument, as long
    # as it's safe: $1 is not checked out, and a fast-forward merge is possible.
    ff = !bash -c '\
           if [[ `git symbolic-ref HEAD` = refs/heads/$1 ]] ";" then \
              echo $1 is checked out, use pull or merge instead. ";" \
           else \
              git update-ref refs/heads/$1 origin/$1 `git merge-base origin/$1 $1` ";" \
           fi' -
```

I often find the unsafe alias useful too, in particular when I do want to discard some work on my local copy of the branch, so I also kept it as `ff-force`:

```
    # Not safe - reset the specified branch to its state on origin, even if it's not a fast-forward merge and potentially throws away some commits
    ff-force = !sh -c 'git update-ref refs/heads/$1 origin/$1' -
```

Known limitation for both my aliases: the remote has to be called `origin`.

Comment: I agree worth keeping this answer even though phd answer is what I was looking for. One thing that would improve your answer is to explain how the update-ref works in this particular case; define a function instead of an alias because then you won't have all these quotes to put in various places, ie code will be simpler to understand and you'll be able to handle different remote name (via optional function arg); and to keep this focused on the OP problem, I would move the safeguard to the end of the answer, as an improvement. JM2CW!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've changed the order of the answer and added some explanations. I'm not sure how I'd define a function in my .gitconfig, though, it seems those have to be done as separate executable files on my path. I prefer containing all my Git customizations in just one place, but I agree a function script would look cleaner.

Comment: Is `git update-ref refs/heads/foo origin/foo` equivalent to `git branch -f foo origin/foo` or is there some difference in behaviour?

Comment: @IMSoP I was not familiar with that `git branch -f` variant. Reading the documentation, it looks like those two commands are indeed doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I do

1. `git fetch origin develop` - get latest changes but don't merge them to the local `develop` -
2. `git merge origin/develop` - merge