# How to update local master and rebase to it using one line command from a dev branch?

Tags: git, rebase

Say I am working on a branch called `dev` that is tracking `master`.
If I want to update my master branch, I need to run these series of commands frequently:

```
git checkout master
git pull 
git checkout dev
git rebase -i master
```

Is there a one-line to achieve above, using git commands while I am on the dev branch (i.e. updating local master and rebase to it)

Comment: Is `rebase --interactive` a requirement? Without it I can do everything in 1 (one) command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copy here [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859568/7976758) with some modifications. I assume your last command should be `git rebase master` (without `-i`).

One command:

```
git pull --rebase origin master:master
```

Let's me split it and explain. `git pull --rebase master:master` is equivalent to

```
git fetch origin master:master
git rebase master
```

`git fetch origin master:master` means: fetch new commits from remote `origin` branch `master` and update local branch `master` to point to the same commit as remote `master`. It's what you do with

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout dev
```

but much faster (no need to do 2 checkouts).

If you need to stash uncommitted changes add `--autostash`:

```
git pull --autostash --rebase origin master:master
```

Answer (score 1):

In Command Prompt in Windows and in Linux bash, you could use `&&`, which executes the right-hand command, the next command of `&&` only if the previous command was successful.