# Checkout git main branch and pull, checkout my branch and merge main on my branch as a single command

Tags: bash, git, alias

I would like to get this four steps in a single command (suppose you start on `custom_branch`):

```bash
git checkout main
git pull
git checkout custom_branch
git merge main
```

I created following alias on my `~/.zshrc`:

```bash
alias git_main_merge="(
 BRANCH=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` && 
 git checkout main && 
 git pull && 
 git checkout $BRANCH && 
 git merge main
)"
```

Is there another git trick to resolve this behaviour without an alias?

Comment: Your variable `BRANCH` is unset at the time you are doing the checkout. It is only defined in the environement of the rev-parse. You can isolate this problem by trying out `BR=foo echo test && echo $BR`, which just outputs _test_, but not _foo_.

Comment: `git pull origin main:main` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859568/7976758

Answer (score 2):

I would skip the shared main branch altogether. Starting when you are on your branch:

```
git pull origin main # adjust the name of the remote if needed
```

**Warning**: this is not something a lot of people do.... actually, I might be the only one doing it... so, sit down and think carefully if you would like to use that. The gist of the concept is **why do you need to keep a local main branch in sync with the remote branch**? If you do not intent to work *separately* in the local `main` branch, what is the point of keeping the local `main` branch in the first place?

Comment: You're not alone :-) I'm often going with `git fetch; git merge origin/main`, but it's the same principle of not bothering to keep an updated local version of `main`.

Comment: @RomainValeri are you my clone? I actually do the same thing. I don't use pull often :-D

Comment: "I AM the original clone!" haha

Comment: I sometimes feel like the lonely (and uncared for) voice of wisdom with that advice :-D

Comment: Git skills slowly pushes you into Cassandra syndrome, I guess :-)

Comment: hahaha good one