# Git shortcuts to pull and merge master

Tags: git

Has anyone successfully created a git shortcut to checkout master, pull, checkout last and then merge the new master?

```bash
$ git config --global alias.refresh 'git checkout master && git pull && git checkout - && git merge master'
```

I tried a couple of variations of this to no avail. If anyone has figured it out I'd love to know.

Comment: `git remote update && git merge origin/master`?

Comment: A lot more simple than I expected. I guess just "git merge origin/master" does the trick

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859568/7976758