# How to fetch not the current branch and merge it with the current, without branch checkout

Tags: git, git-branch, kill, git-checkout

I usually work in the project which branches have so many differences, branch checkout is similar to start a new project. With branch checkout, IDE just hangs because too many changes (more than 2 million) happen in one time, and I need kill it through Task Manager. With branch checkout, I need to reinstall dependencies, usually.

I want to avoid and fetch specific branch and merge it with the current one I work on without need to checkout. Is it possible?

Something like:

`git fetch <somebranch>`
`git merge <somebranch>`

Comment: a side note: is "2 million" the actual number of changes ? what do you version in this git repository ?

Comment: @LeGEC We encountered missing dependencies several times and decided to commit node_modules in repo. This is why (not my article): https://medium.com/@chaitanyagiri/defending-my-choice-to-commit-node-modules-to-git-8eb02badd279

Answer (score 0):

After you have run `git fetch`, all the remote references are updated, so you can run `git merge origin/<somebranch>`.

You can also update any local branch, which is not the active branch, by running:

```
git fetch origin <somebranch>:<somebranch>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859568/7976758 `git pull origin <somebranch>:<somebranch>` both fetches and merges into the current.