# How to update local master and merge a feature branch in a shorter way

Tags: git

My workflow to merge my feature branch with upstream remote is:

```
git stash / commit # save current work on feature branch
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout feature
git merge master
```

It seems to me I'm doing one too many steps. Is there a shorter workflow to achieve this? I could perhaps run `git fetch` and merge with `origin/master` but then my local master would go out of date?

Comment: “my local master would go out of date?”—What do you need local `master` for? Yeah, you can just merge `origin/master` directly into your feature branch. Don’t need to update your own `master`, really. (Thanks to user matt on this site for this tip.)

Comment: Yeah that is doable. I routinely update my local master because I'm used to branching off of it. Hence I prefer merging with my local master than origin/master. But if there is no other way, then that's what I'll consider doing!

Comment: `git pull --autostash origin master:master` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859568/7976758

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! That question is exactly what I'm looking for too. Too bad I wasn't able to find it

Answer (score 2):

You're correct.
You can do

```
git commit
git fetch
git merge origin/master
```

git fetch will get the latest changes from origin onto the origin/master branch allowing you to merge it into your feature branch.

Comment: You can use `git fetch origin master:master` to fast-forward update the local master branch to match origin/master.  If you do that as well as (or instead of) the `git fetch`, then the last command can be just `git merge master`

Comment: Oooo That is exactly what I was looking for. If you add that as an answer, I'd happily accept as the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to update your "local master", or change to the `master` branch in order to update `origin/master`, which is the thing you actually want to keep up-to-date with. All you need is `git fetch` which pulls in changes from the remote.

Once you've pulled in changes, you can `rebase` onto `origin/master` to move the commits from your branch on top of whatever has come in from the remote. I typically use `rebase -i` for this, so I can review the commits I'm moving.

The full set of steps is:

```
git fetch
git stash
git rebase -i origin/master
git stash pop
```

Note that, as is always the case when rebasing, you should make sure you are the only person working on the branch. Otherwise you will create divergent branches and there will be problems when other people try to incorporate your changes.