Pull and rebase from master in same time
I want to optimize the following process:
branch A> checkout master
master  > git pull
master  > checkout branch A
branch A> git rebase master 

Is it possible to do these commands in one command?

Is git pull --rebase origin master:master good enough? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859568/7976758

I like that one, @phd..... I would raise the question as to why the OP wants to keep the local branch in sync with the remote. How would it work if you did not have a local master branch to update?

@eftshift0 My command (re)creates it. Without it there will be 2 commands: git fetch origin master && git rebase origin/master

In my opinion this is an xy question — by which I mean that I don't agree with the implicit premise of the question. There is in fact no reason to have a local master in the first place. So step one would be to say
git branch -D master

to get rid of it.
From then on, to rebase your current feature branch onto the latest version of master, you would say
git fetch && git rebase origin/master

Observe how this gets rid of the silly game of switching to a local master merely so you can switch back to your feature branch and rebase it.
For more information on how to use Git nimbly and without a local main branch, see my essay here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72201388/341994

You can still have a local master and update it without checking it out first: git fetch origin master:master (and then … && git rebase master)

@knittl 100% true

use bash aliases for that:
alias gitupfull="git commit -a -m 'commit before rebase' || true && git checkout main && git pull --rebase && git checkout - && git rebase main"

git checkout - allows to switch to previous branch, so no need to specify your initial branch

What is gitco ?

oh it's my another frequently used alias alias gitco="git checkout"

My Advice: please either put it into the answer or better expand it so anyone can just copy the alias from the answer.
