Workflow for syncing dev branch with master
I created a dev branch from master branch and then added few commits into the dev branch. Now I want to pull the changes from the master branch into the dev branch. Here are the steps which I think should make my dev branch in sync with the master branch:
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout dev
git merge master

Are the above steps correct or am I doing anything incorrectly here? Please suggest.

I suggest that it is correct. When you did that, was the result as you expected?

You can do everything in one command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859568/7976758 git pull origin master:master

What you're doing works, but there sure is a lot of wasted motion.
If you are on dev, there is no need to switch back to master merely to update master (and then switch back to dev in order to merge into it). It would be sufficient, in your situation, to say (on dev):
git fetch origin master:master
git merge master

But I would go even further. If, as is typically the case, the only purpose of the master branch is to have a place for you and your co-workers to merge to by way of a PR at the remote end, then you have no need for a local master at all. Delete it:
git branch -D master

Now your dev-updating flow will look like this:
git fetch
git merge origin/master

I like this way of saying things in particular because you are saying what you mean — update my copy of the remote master and merge that into the branch I'm in now.

Thanks @matt. In the command to fetch changes from master what does master:master signify?

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt-ltrefspecgt
